# Website not loading in my device but works in other device

Tags: windows, dns, website

My website (https://wikifox.ml) is working fine in my cell phone but not working in my PC, It is showing like this (`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`)

[image]

I tried clearing DNS cache using the below command and didn't work!

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you guys find wrong with vanilla wikipedia in the first place but anyhow ...

The url is pointing to 3.67.234.155 and the server seems fine.

It is just a problem with your local DNS configuration. Maybe try pointing it to `8.8.8.8` directly or `1.1.1.1` or something like this *(for a quick fix, otherwise would need details)*.

Comment: Yo! That worked!